# Would relativity violate conservation of energy?

Tags: special-relativity, energy-conservation

My understanding of the relativity theory is that when an object is travelling at near-light speed, time will pass much slower for it than for the stationary observer.

Doesn't this mean that as an object accelerates to nearer and nearer light speed, it will actually "slow down" in the stationary reference frame?

Wouldnt this imply a violation of energy conservation since more energy being converted to kinetic motion is actually resulting in less kinetic energy?

For example consider a spaceship sent from earth going to a distant planet. Lets say that if the spaceship travelled at 80% the speed of light, it would arrive in 100 years for the stationary observer. Now if the same ship travelled at 99.999% light speed it would suddenly take about 12000 years, effectively slowing down despite more energy being used to accelerate.

Comment: I don't understand your reasoning. If the spacecraft has speed $0.8c$ according to Alice, the spacecraft travels 80 light-years in 100 years. A spacecraft that has speed $0.99999c$ according to Alice would take 80.0008 years to travel the same distance, not 12000 years.

Comment: Kinetic energy is frame dependent

Comment: If Special Relativity violated the conservation of energy, Einstein would be even more famous than he already is, and textbooks would not use the conservation of energy to solve problems about relativistic particle collisions.

Comment: @G.Smith Proof by famousness.

Comment: @DavideMorgante This isn’t supposed to be a proof. This is supposed to be a clue that the answer is “No” and that the question shouldn’t have been phrased as misleadingly suggesting that SR does violate energy conservation.

Comment: @G.Smith Yeah, of course. But i found it funny anyway!

Comment: A more reasonable question would have been “Why doesn’t SR violate...?” or “Does SR violate...?”. “*Would* SR violate...?” is essentially an off-topic personal theory.

Answer (score 1):

Special relativity does not violate energy conservation!

As mentioned in the comments of the origynal post (by Alfred Centauri): "If the spacecraft has speed 0.8c according to Alice, the spacecraft travels 80 light-years in 100 years. A spacecraft that has speed 0.99999c according to Alice would take 80.0008 years to travel the same distance, not 12000 years."

What you are thinking about is the following. Lets say Alfred travels and **on the ship**. Lets say that Alice can see Alfred's clock with a good telescope, and Alice sees that on Alfred's clock 1 s elapsed. If he is travelling with 0.8 c, than the elapsed time for Alice on Earth (according to her own clock) is 1.7 s. And if Alfred travels with 0.99999 c, than the elapsed time for Alice is 223.6 s. (This is called [time dilation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_dilation).)

This can be calculated with the formula:

$$T=\frac{T_0}{\sqrt{1-v^2/c^2}}$$

where $T_0$ is the elapsed time (seen by Alice) on the spaceship, and T is the elapsed time on Earth. ($v$ is the speed of space ship relative to Earth).

Comment: Ok I think I see my error. I reversed how time dilation works. So for Alice it would take 80 years for the ship to arrive, but for Alfred it would only be 100/223.6 years = 5 months. I was thinking Alfred would perceive the 80 years, so Alice would perceive 18000.

Comment: @YellowBadger Notice that, for Alfred the jurney would take 5 month according to his **own** clock not because of time dilation, but [Lorentz contraction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Length_contraction). In his own frame, the time is 'normal', but the distance between the planets is less. (As in his own frame the planets are moving together.)